# Share dependency versions across multiple Version Catalogs

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-plugin

I'm trying to find a way to share a dependency's version across multiple Version Catalog toml files.

For example, say I have the following two Version Catalog toml files:

`libs.versions.toml`

```ini
[versions]
dagger = "2.42"

[libraries]
dagger-android = { module = "com.google.dagger:dagger-android", version.ref = "dagger" }
```

`buildLibs.versions.toml`

```ini
[versions]
dagger = "2.42"

[libraries]
hiltAndroidGradlePlugin = { module = "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin", version.ref = "dagger" }
```

I use the **same** `dagger` version across both Version Catalogs, and when I need to bump the `dagger` version I have to remember to update *all* toml files.

My workaround is to share the version using the Version Catalog builder API by doing:

In my `settings.gradle`

```
ext.sharedVersions = [ dagger : "2.42"]

dependencyResolutionManagement {
    versionCatalogs {
        libs {
            version('dagger', sharedVersions.dagger)
            library('dagger-android', 'com.google.dagger', 'dagger-android').versionRef('dagger')
        }
        buildLibs {
            version('dagger', sharedVersions.dagger)
            library('hiltAndroidGradlePlugin', 'com.google.dagger', 'hilt-android-gradle-plugin').versionRef('dagger')
        }
    }
}
```

which works, but takes away from my dependencies being centralized as some are declared in toml files, while other are declared in `settings.gradle`.

Comment: Maybe it's something very obvious, but I'm curious anyway: why wouldn't just extract these shared dependencies into a separate catalog? So eventually it's going to be: `libs.versions.toml`, `buildLibs.versions.toml` and, let's say, `sharedLibs.versions.toml`?

Comment: Or it's possible to group dependency catalogs by providers: `androidLibs.versions.toml`, `kotlinLibs.versions.toml`, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of now, the Version Catalog Builder API is the recommended solution.

https://discuss.gradle.org/t/share-dependency-versions-across-multiple-version-catalogs/43145